# Why should all packets pass load balancer instead of redirecting client to a specific server?

Tags: load-balancing

I am trying to understand how load balancing works.

Currently, as far as I understand, all the network packets are passing through load balancers. But this obviously looks making LB itself as a bottleneck. It would be better redirecting clients to a specific server directly.

So, why most of LB configuration shows all the packets are passing through LB machine?